# Python (3.5.2, Anaconda custom [64-bit]) Error Loading Shared Libraries (libintlc.so.5)

Tags: bash, python-3.5, libraries, qsub, pbs

I'm running a bash script using qstat. It runs fine going line-by-line in an interactive shell (i.e. /bin/bash) and if I run it as `bash test_script.sh`. However, when I submit it via qstat as `qstat test_script.sh`, I get an error along the lines of:

```
python: error while loading shared libraries: libintlc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The file is set up with the required PBS directives and the bash is as follows:

```
source ~/.bashrc
module load /path/to/anaconda/python/version
cd ~/path/to/files/
python python_file.py > python_logfile.out
```

I'm running out of things to check here, so any advice would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Run the script with strace. This will hopefully give you an indication of where is looking for the shared libraries. Could be versioning issue.

Comment: @RamanSailopal I tried running with strace (which was installed) but run into permission errors... I don't know if I have administrative access.

Comment: Can you not run with sudo?